# pgsql slow query on table of 500 million rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table that keeps measurements of latencies between nodes running MPI tasks in a large cluster. The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE latency(
from_rank int,
to_rank int,
from_host varchar(20),
to_host varchar(20),
from_cpu varchar(20),
to_cpu varchar(20),
latency float8);

CREATE INDEX ON latency(from_host, to_host);
```

Now after a large experiment I collected over 500 million rows of data. I find querying these data painfully slow, below is an example of a SELECT COUNT(*)

```
psql (9.4devel)
Type "help" for help.

routing=# \timing 
Timing is on.
routing=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM latency;
   count   
-----------
 522190848
(1 row)

Time: 759462.969 ms
routing=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM latency;
   count   
-----------
 522190848
(1 row)

Time: 96775.036 ms
routing=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM latency;
   count   
-----------
 522190848
(1 row)

Time: 97708.132 ms
routing=#
```

I am running both the PgSQL server and client on the same machine, which has 4 Xeon E7-4870s (40 cores/80 threads in total) and 1 TB of RAM. The effect of Linux file caching is obvious: the first query took well over 12mins while the subsequent ones took about 1.5min.

Is there anything I can do to make the query run faster, since 1.5min isn't exactly responsive.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the only information you want from the database the total number of rows?

Comment: lol no I'm using that as an example. My other query (involves a inner join with another table of about 2mil rows) hasn't returned yet. it's been running for over an hour.

Comment: We can't help you diagnose this other query without seeing it.

Comment: How about posting some details about your server, along with the real queries that are not performing. Start with the output of the following query, followed by `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` of your slow query.
`SELECT name, current_setting(name), source
FROM pg_settings
WHERE source NOT IN ('default', 'override')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'version' as name, version(), null;`
Also, did you run ANALYZE before running your slow query(ies)?

Comment: @bma did not know about EXPLAIN and ANALYZE (still pretty new to PgSQL), will try 'em out, thanks.

Comment: Being in charge of a 500mm row table on your kind of hardware and not knowing about `EXPLAIN` are two wildly conflicting pieces of information. You may need someone with a little experience to configure your system properly. Or you need to [start reading](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/index.html).

Comment: Here is a good guide to posting performance problems (generally to the postgresql mailing lists, but it applies to S.O. too): https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: Please see the guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info for good info to collect for diagnostics.

Comment: In addition to the above questions, what is your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: hi guys thanks for your comments. I do have to start reading and thanks for the links you gave me. @ErwinBrandstetter I'm in this weird situation (powerful machine, newbie user) because the machine is not a dedicated database server. rather, we are a large research lab and this powerful machine is shared between users with LSF (a PBS like system). When I have a reservation, I have the machine all to myself and can start the PgSQL server and also use the client locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For postgres, unlike other RDBMS, `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` from an unindexed table means a full scan of the table. So the first run is purely IO bound. If you want this query - consider adding some indexes to the table. (Without knowing the query I can not tell, what indexes you may need).

Another option - configure postgres to better utilize the RAM you have.

Comment: This is true even on a table with a suitable index until 9.2 (with index-only scans).

Comment: **Every** DBMS that implements proper transaction handling will need to scan the whole table if no index is available.